# C# Capturing an already running Process's STDOut

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to capture a processes standard out stream after it has already been started.

ie. something like this pseudo code:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(1234);
process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
process.ErrorDataReceived += process_ErrorDataReceived;
process.Exited += process_Exited;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Id love a solution that doesn't force me to create pipes or call native code if possible etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Also `process.BeginOutputReadLine();` may be of use.

Ofcourse this is assuming the original process was started with `UseShellExecute = false` and `RedirectStandardOutput = true`

**EDIT**

As the process was possibly started using the shell and without redirection of stdout. Have a look at http://pastebin.com/f3eda7c8

Comment: The original process was not started with `RedirectStandardOutput = true`. I'm wanting to grab a process and redirect it after launch.

Comment: That pastebin stuff works only for the current process, not any other process, does it? It uses [SetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setstdhandle) and according to MSDN you can't simply specify any handle of any process.